# Handle redirection to login page from server using angular 4 client

Tags: angular, authentication, spring-boot, cas

Server uses CAS authentication.
Client sends a request to Server, Server responds with redirect to CAS login page with redirect-url referring to client's request.

redirection to login url:

```
https://cas1.company.com/cas/login?service=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fwebapi%2Fj_spring_cas_security_check%3Fredirect-url%3DaHR0cDovL2xvY2FsaG9zdDo4MDgwL3dlYmFwaS91c2Vycw
```

If I don't use angular client and use browser request, I get login page and after logging in, it serves my request.

How to handle this scenario with angular 4?

I need to let server serve the login page after logging in, I need to get the redirect-url portion of the login page and send another request to server using Authorization header with Bearer token.

I have seen redirection to login page from angular client itself using AuthGuard's CanActivate method, but, my case seems to be different.

Is there any example I can follow for my use-case?

Comment: So you want to redirect based on return_url without using AuthGuard? How did you setup the application to detect if the user is authorised, and thus if not direct them to login page?

Comment: @Aeseir We have a template that we currently follow in the backend. There is a custom JWTFilter in the backend which looks for Authorization header/ access_token request parameter and determines if the user is authorized after validating the token using token provider. If not, it constructs a url with redirect-url pointing to original request url and does a sendRedirect on the request to the login page.

Comment: So how does the user access the backend, i am assuming you have a angular front end that triggers some type of call to backend am i correct?

Comment: @Aeseir What we are doing is similar to what he said in this stackoverflow reply: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28323747/how-to-use-angularjs-routing-with-cas-authentication-redirect-or-is-angular-jus

User is internal and will have the link to the internal app's front page. But, the cas-url is on the backend and backend handles the redirection to login page.

Comment: I think I should ask how to make angular-client display login page after backend does the redirection?

Comment: This is why I was asking about the flow and structure. If you use AuthGuard, you can easily then read response from backend and if login required, you direct it to the login. After login they can be redirected back to the angular-client